# how can I create a new project in yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm trying to follow the directions but after the `init` part I am lost. Where is this database that it speaks of? I don't see this `config/db.php`. Why can't I just create a new webapp like before (I searched somewhere and it said to do `yii  app/create` (can't remember) but that did not work. How can I just create one?

I'm stuck with this screen at the moment.
when i click on this `//local/project/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin`
i get `Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is that you folow the [getting started](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/getting-started.md), also You can run with composer 
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic

Comment: yup past that part. It seems like the path is not correct or something?? Why does it show the directory like that rather than the view?

Comment: you access to frontend/backend with the url
http://youproject/frontend/web or http://youproject/frontend/web
but before you must run the command init, for setting the enviroment of work

Comment: ummm, the image show the root of the project, can you show the frontend or backend folder?

Comment: oooh frontend is fine. backend please see the image.

Comment: php version? chek the system [requeriment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-yii.html#requirements-and-prerequisites) because not is error of Yii

Answer (score -2):

You need to get access key from github and then follow [the procedure from the Yii documentation](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/installing-yii2/)